# RStudio / Quarto not rendering PDF or HTML

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I cannot render the following quarto document in RStudio:

```
---
title: "Quarto Demo"
author: "Test"
date: "2022-5-24"
---
```

The error I receive back is:

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any idea why this would be the case?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this was because of a space in the filename. Once I removed the space in the filename then it rendered.